# Destroy previous ViewPager item preventing back scrolling

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've added my code in below including some things I've tried. What I want is a sliding viewpager which doesn't allow you to through previous items but only forward. Preferably I would like to also only allow forward (right to left) scrolling if a certain checkbox is checked within the current fragment allowing progress to the next.

I've considered

- removing the previous fragment once the current fragment is displayed and idle
- setting the adapter (i.e. this: `mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);`) again once I've reset the count and removed the first fragment to cause a "refresh"
- using an onTouchListener on the ViewPager and using motionevent

The code below using `mPager.removeViewAt(0)` does not work as it doesn't prevent scrolling, just literally removes the view leaving a blank screen in it's place.

What's the best way to do this? Maybe I'm not even using the right adapter as I've literally started using fragments from yesterday.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager);
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageListener());
}

public OnPageChangeListener mPageListener() {
    OnPageChangeListener listener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {}

        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            if (arg0 == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && mPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
                mPager.removeViewAt(0);
                mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //mPagerAdapter.destroyItem(mPager, arg0, mPagerAdapter.getItem(arg0));
            }
        }
    };
    return listener;
}

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        Fragment fragment = new PracticeModeFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}

public class PracticeModeFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,
                container, false);
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.count)).setText(""
                + getArguments().getInt("position"));
        return rootView;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are using the wrong tool. ViewPager is not meant to be used that way.

Just replace the fragments using the [FragmentManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) and [FragmentTransactions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html). By doing so, you will have complete control over the back stack and transactions.

You can also manually add gestures to the fragments to simulate the ViewPager effect. [Here's a tutorial for that.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html)

Comment: I'm having trouble using fragmentmanager and transactions. Is there any way you could show me, please and thanks? Also will the manual gestures allow me to have the same edge to edge swipe animation?

Comment: You should use FragmentTransaction.replace [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int, android.app.Fragment, java.lang.String)) to remove the old fragment and add the new one on top. Regarding the gestures, you first need to create them using the GestureBuilder sdk app. Follow the complete tutorial.